# Injecting a generic factory in Guice

Tags: java, generics, dependency-injection, guice

The following code is an example of a factory that produces a `Bar<T>` given a `Foo<T>`. The factory doesn't care what `T` is: for any type `T`, it can make a `Bar<T>` from a `Foo<T>`.

```
import com.google.inject.*;
import com.google.inject.assistedinject.*;

class Foo<T> {
  public void flip(T x) { System.out.println("flip: " + x); }
}

interface Bar<T> {
  void flipflop(T x);
}

class BarImpl<T> implements Bar<T> {
  Foo<T> foo;

  @Inject
  BarImpl(Foo<T> foo) { this.foo = foo; }

  public void flipflop(T x) { foo.flip(x); System.out.println("flop: " + x); }
}

interface BarFactory {
  <T> Bar<T> create(Foo<T> f);
}

class Module extends AbstractModule {
  public void configure() {
    bind(BarFactory.class)
      .toProvider( 
          FactoryProvider.newFactory( BarFactory.class, BarImpl.class ) 
                   );
  }
}

public class GenericInject {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new Module());

    Foo<Integer> foo = new Foo<Integer>();
    Bar<Integer> bar = injector.getInstance(BarFactory.class).create(foo);
    bar.flipflop(0);
  }
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following errors from Guice:

```
1) No implementation for BarFactory was bound.
  at Module.configure(GenericInject.java:38)

2) Bar<T> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.
```

The only reference I can find to generics in the Guice documentation says to use a `TypeLiteral`. But I don't have a literal type, I have a generic placeholder that isn't relevant to the factory at all. Any tips?

Answer (score 4):

One option is to just write the BarFactory boilerplate by hand:

```
class BarImplFactory implements BarFactory {
  public <T> Bar<T> create(Foo<T> f) {
    return new BarImpl(f);
  }
}
```

The binding becomes

```
bind(BarFactory.class).to(BarImplFactory.class);
```

Comment: Will Guice inject `BarImpl`'s other constructor parameters even if its constructor is being called explicitly without Guice?

Comment: No, I don't think so. You'll still need to provide your own Foos.

Comment: @Jeff Axelrod, You can inject BarImpl's other constructor params by first injecting to BarImplFactory's constructor, and then copying those values.

Answer (score -1):

If you think of guice as a system of wiring similar to spring, then it doesn't really make sense to wire a generic instance. You're wiring specific instances to keys, so that when another instantiated class marks something with @Inject BarFactory you get the specific created instance.

Since your implementation is generic, you haven't provided enough information to inject a specific instance. Although I haven't used factoryprovider, my assumption is that you'll need to bind the Barfactory to a fully parameterized instance, e.g. `BarImpl<Concrete>` instead of BarImpl )

Incidentally since you're binding BarFactory.class if you want to bind multiple instances you're going to have to inflect them somehow, either by name, something like  (haven't checked the syntax, but)

```
bind(BarFactory.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("name1"))
      .toProvider( 

or by generics, bind(BarFactory<Concrete>).toProvider...
```

Comment: BarFactory isn't generic, so it makes perfect sense to wire it the way I've wired it. A parameterized instance of Bar wouldn't match the contract: create needs to to take a Foo<T> and return a Bar<T> for any T.