# Generics Hell: Can I construct a TypeLiteral<Set<T>> using generics?

Tags: java, generics, types, set, guice

The only way I was able to get the below generic method to work was to pass the seemingly redundant `TypeLiteral<Set<T>>` parameter.  I believe it should be possible to construct this parameter programmatically given the other parameter, but can't figure out how.

```
protected <T> Key<Set<T>> bindMultibinder(
 TypeLiteral<Set<T>> superClassSet, TypeLiteral<T> superClass) {
   final Key<Set<T>> multibinderKey = Key.get(superClassSet, randomAnnotation);
   return multibinderKey;
}
```

Client code looks like:

```
bindMultibinder(new TypeLiteral<Set<A<B>>>(){}, new TypeLiteral<A<B>>(){});
```

Where A and B are interfaces.

If I try the following (removing the `TypeLiteral<Set<T>> superClassSet` parameter), I get a `java.util.Set<T> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.` runtime error.

```
protected <T> Key<Set<T>> bindMultibinder(TypeLiteral<T> superClass) {
   final Key<Set<T>> multibinderKey = Key.get(
    new TypeLiteral<Set<T>>() {}, randomAnnotation);
   return multibinderKey;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581137/injecting-generics-with-guice and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791839/injecting-a-generic-factory-in-guice

Comment: what do you pass as a `TypeLiteral<Set<T>>` parameter?

Comment: @alf The first method works correctly.  It can be called, for example, like this:  `bindMultibinder(new TypeLiteral<Set<A<B>>>(){}, new TypeLiteral<A<B>>(){});`

Comment: Where `A` and `B` are concrete classes, not type literals?

Comment: See also this related [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16903252/928711)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Fully specified* means that the values of all type parameters are known. Constructing a fully specified `TypeLiteral<Set<T>>` from a `TypeLiteral<T>` appears to be impossible using the Guice public API. Specifically, `TypeLiteral` only has two constructors. The first is:

```
/**
 * Constructs a new type literal. Derives represented class from type
 * parameter.
 *
 * <p>Clients create an empty anonymous subclass. Doing so embeds the type
 * parameter in the anonymous class's type hierarchy so we can reconstitute it
 * at runtime despite erasure.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected TypeLiteral() {
  this.type = getSuperclassTypeParameter(getClass());
  this.rawType = (Class<? super T>) MoreTypes.getRawType(type);
  this.hashCode = type.hashCode();
}
```

This constructor attempts to deduce the values of type parameters from the `TypeLiteral`'s runtime class. This will yield a *fully specified* type only if the runtime class determines the type parameter. However, because all instances of a generic class share the same runtime class (that is, `new HashSet<String>().getClass() == new HashSet<Integer>().getClass()`, the type parameter is only known if a *non-generic* subclass of `TypeLiteral` is instantiated. That is, we can't reuse the same class declaration for different values of `T`, but must define a new class for each `T`. This is rather cumbersome, as alf's answer demonstrates.

This leaves us with the other constructor, which is more helpful, but not part of the public API:

```
/**
 * Unsafe. Constructs a type literal manually.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
TypeLiteral(Type type) {
  this.type = canonicalize(checkNotNull(type, "type"));
  this.rawType = (Class<? super T>) MoreTypes.getRawType(this.type);
  this.hashCode = this.type.hashCode();
}
```

We can use this constructor as follows:

```
package com.google.inject;

import java.util.Set;

import com.google.inject.internal.MoreTypes;

public class Types {
    public static <T> TypeLiteral<Set<T>> setOf(TypeLiteral<T> lit) {
        return new TypeLiteral<Set<T>>(new MoreTypes.ParameterizedTypeImpl(null, Set.class, lit.getType())); 
    }
}
```

Testcase:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(setOf(new TypeLiteral<String>() {}));
}
```

In a perfect world, Guice would offer a public API to accomplish this ...

Comment: Yeah, looks much easier :) Thank you, I did hope my exercise is not the only way :)

Comment: @alf One way to achieve this, is to use `com.google.inject.util.Types` which provides the necessary API

Answer (score 15):

Please forgive me if you already know most of the answer: it's hard to make an assumption on your level.

The reason of the problem is type erasure, as you know already.  In order to get rid of type erasure, Guice uses a trick with concrete ancestors, as shown below:

```
class Trick<T> {
    T t;
}

public class GenericTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Trick<Set<String>> trick = new Trick<Set<String>>() {
        };

        // Prints "class org.acm.afilippov.GenericTest$1"
        System.out.println(trick.getClass());
        // Prints "org.acm.afilippov.Trick<java.util.Set<java.lang.String>>"
        System.out.println(trick.getClass().getGenericSuperclass());
    }
}
```

Point is, when you create a class which extends a generic superclass *and explicitly specifies the type parameter,* you will usually need to write [metods which accept that very specific type, and these methods' signatures cannot be erased](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ103). In this case we have no problem discussed in FAQ, but compiler saves the type information, anyway: the users of your class will need to know the exact types in order to use the methods.

Now your version does not have a concrete class inherited from `TypeLiteral<Set<YourSpecificType>>`, it only has `TypeLiteral<Set<T>>`—and that's where it all fails.

Changing my little example, that would be:

```
public class GenericTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tryMe(String.class);
    }

    private static <T> void tryMe(Class<T> clazz) {
        Trick<Set<T>> trick = new Trick<Set<T>>() {
        };

        // Prints "class org.acm.afilippov.GenericTest$1"
        System.out.println(trick.getClass());
        // Prints "org.acm.afilippov.Trick<java.util.Set<T>>"
        System.out.println(trick.getClass().getGenericSuperclass());
    }
}
```

As you can see, our `GenericTest$1` is not concrete any more: it still have a type parameter, and its concrete value, here `String`, is lost during the compilation.

You can of course avoid that, but in order to do so, you need to *create a class* with a specific type parameter used for inheritance—so that Guice would be able to work out the details. Wait a bit, I'll try to come up with an example.

Update: it turned out to be a VERY long bit. So here's an updated version for you:

```
public class GenericTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        tryMe(String.class);
    }

    private static <T> void tryMe(Class<T> clazz) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        Class c = loadClass("org.acm.afilippov.ASMTrick", generateClass(clazz));

        Trick<Set<T>> trick = (Trick<Set<T>>) c.newInstance();

        // Prints "class org.acm.afilippov.ASMTrick"
        System.out.println(trick.getClass());
        // Prints "org.acm.afilippov.Trick<java.util.Set<java.lang.String>>"
        System.out.println(trick.getClass().getGenericSuperclass());
    }

    private static byte[] generateClass(Class<?> element) {
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(0);
        MethodVisitor mv;

        cw.visit(V1_6, ACC_FINAL + ACC_SUPER, "org/acm/afilippov/ASMTrick",
                "Lorg/acm/afilippov/Trick<Ljava/util/Set<L" + element.getName().replaceAll("\\.", "/") + ";>;>;",
                "org/acm/afilippov/Trick", null);

        {
            mv = cw.visitMethod(0, "<init>", "()V", null, null);
            mv.visitCode();
            mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "org/acm/afilippov/Trick", "<init>", "()V");
            mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
            mv.visitMaxs(1, 1);
            mv.visitEnd();
        }
        cw.visitEnd();

        return cw.toByteArray();
    }

    private static Class loadClass(String className, byte[] b) {
        //override classDefine (as it is protected) and define the class.
        Class clazz = null;
        try {
            ClassLoader loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
            Class cls = Class.forName("java.lang.ClassLoader");
            java.lang.reflect.Method method =
                    cls.getDeclaredMethod("defineClass", new Class[]{String.class, byte[].class, int.class, int.class});

            // protected method invocaton
            method.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                Object[] args = new Object[]{className, b, new Integer(0), new Integer(b.length)};
                clazz = (Class) method.invoke(loader, args);
            } finally {
                method.setAccessible(false);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return clazz;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the type information is now preserved. I believe this approach is not used because it's way too painful even for this draft.