# Retrieve a singleton by type and annotation using Guice

Tags: java, guice

I have several classes implementing `interface Provider<Communication>` and I'm using Guice with a `@Named` annotation to bind them as required, e.g.:

```
@Singleton
public class Verizon implements Provider<Call> {
  ...
}

@Singleton
public class TMobile implements Provider<Call> {
  ...
}

bind (new TypeLiteral<Provider<Call>>() {}).annotatedWith(
  Names.named("Verizon")).to(Verizon.class);

bind (new TypeLiteral<Provider<Call>>() {}).annotatedWith(
  Names.named("TMobile")).to(TMobile.class);
```

Is there a clean way to implement a factory that takes the name as a parameter, e.g.:

```
public static <C extends Communication> Provider<C> getCallProvider(C communication) {
  String providerName = communication.getProviderName();

  return [Guice's matching object for type Provider<?> and @Named = providerName];
}
```

I've attempted using Injector but Guice won't take a generic as parameter to TypeLiteral:

```
public <C extends Communication> Provider<C> getCommunicationProvider(C communication) {
  return injector.getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<CommunicationProvider<C>>() {},
    Names.named(communication.getProvider().getId())));
}
```

This throws:

```
com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:
  1) Provider<C> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providers are managed by Guice; when you bind a `Foo` or `Provider<Foo>` correctly, you should be able to ask for a `Foo` or `Provider<Foo>` without any additional work. Therefore, you probably don't want this:

```
bind (new TypeLiteral<Provider<Call>>() {}).annotatedWith(
  Names.named("Verizon")).to(Verizon.class);
```

Instead you probably want this:

```
bind(Call.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("Verizon")).toProvider(Verizon.class);
```

...which will let you inject `@Named("Verizon") Provider<Call>` but also `@Named("Verizon") call`. At that point your original request is as easy as this:

```
/**
 * Because of erasure, at compile time the injector can only guarantee that it
 * returns something that extends Communication, not necessarily C. The cast and
 * @SuppressWarnings will help with that.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <C extends Communication> Provider<C> getCommunicationProvider(
    C communication) {
  return (Provider<C>) injector.getProvider(Key.get(communication.getClass(),
      Names.named(communication.toString())));
}
```

Note also that because of erasure, there's no other way to get a class literal of type C, so using a mock or dynamic proxy of `Call` will fail.

If you wanted to bind `SomeOtherInterface<Call>` instead of `Provider<Call>`, you could still do so, but you would need to dynamically create a ParameterizedType using Guice's [`Types` util class](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/core/src/com/google/inject/util/Types.java#49) and use that as the input to [`Key#get(Type, Annotation)`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Key.html#get(java.lang.reflect.Type,%20java.lang.annotation.Annotation)). For a little more context on creating a [ParameterizedType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html) implementation, read up at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772555/generics-hell-can-i-construct-a-typeliteralsett-using-generics).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible. You could write a factory yourself and change your code from using the interface to using the factory. Or you can bind your Interface to a Provder (but this will  lead to more code not to less).

```
bind (new TypeLiteral<Provider<Call>>() {}).annotatedWith(
    Names.named("Verizon")).toProvider(new Provider<Provider<Call>>(){public Provider get(){return new Verizon();}});
```

(Or is YOUR Provider the Guice-Provider?)

Comment: The problem with that approach is that the Factory would have to be aware of all possible types - I am on the other hand trying to keep things as generic as possible.

Comment: A factory should know, what to create ... If not, use Reflections-API and use a naming-pattern to find a concrete implementation. But I think this is more  ugly, than a factory knowing all classes.