# Guice, unable to bind ClassTag[T] (to know the name of T class)

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, guice, scala-reflect

I would like to know the name of a generic class.

The solution I use now is the following one. I defined the class `class A[T: ClassTag] {...}` to be able to do `classTag[T].toString`.

This compiles, but there is a problem with Guice. I get the error `No implementation for scala.reflect.ClassTag<com.test.Person> was bound`.

Is there :

- Another solution to know the name of a generic class that could work with Guice ? or
- A way to bind `ClassTag[T]` with Guice ?

Full code :

```
package com.test

case class Person(age: Int)

class A[T: ClassTag] {

  // I need to know the (full) name of type T (e.g. com.test.Person)
  val tClassName = classTag[T].toString

}

class B @Inject()(a: A[Person]) {

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use Guice's `TypeLiteral` instead of `ClassTag`?

Comment: I have found some topics to use `TypeLiteral` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772555/generics-hell-can-i-construct-a-typeliteralsett-using-generics https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-guice/1jbWcdeCF6U . I tried to implement that in Scala with Guice but I didn't succed.  Ex : `@Provides
    def provideTest[T: ClassTag](): TypeLiteral[ClassTag[T]] = {
      TypeLiteral.get(Types.newParameterizedType(ClassTag.getClass, classTag[T].getClass))
    }` (does not compile). Any idea ?

Comment: Not sure what you're doing there, but I really did mean *instead of* `ClassTag`.

Comment: I do not see what you mean. Could you give me an exemple please.

Comment: From a `TypeLiteral<Person>`, you can use `typeLiteral.getType().getTypeName()` to get the full name of `Person`.  I don't know Scala so I can't really give a Scala example.  But the issue is that `ClassTag<T>` isn't injectable, while `TypeLiteral<T>` is.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @tavian-barnes help, I found the way to solve this problem.
The solution is to add to `A` an implicit value `TypeLiteral[T]`. Then, you just have to call `typeLiteral.getType.getTypeName` to get the full name of geneirc class `T`.

Full code :

```
package com.test

case class Person(age: Int)

class A[T]()(implicit val typeLiteral: TypeLiteral[T]) {

  val tClassName = typeLiteral.getType.getTypeName

}

class B @Inject()(a: A[Person]) {

    println(a.tClassName) // prints `com.test.Person`

}
```